# using python to see if specific string is in text file

Tags: python

I'm creating a google search chatbot with voice recognition. I created a text file with the key words being,

search,
who is,
what is,
where is,

The idea is that if the user says any of those phrases it'll know to do a google search but, the user will say 'who is john lennon' and my program won't recognise that command, even though it has 'who is'. How would i be able to make it handle the object that they are searching? This is my code:

```
#MODULES AND LIBARYS USED
import win32com.client as wincl #AI VOICE
import speech_recognition as sr #SPEECH RECGN
from datetime import datetime #DATE AND TIME
import time #TIME MODULE
from aicomm import *
from aifunc import *
#STATIC OBJECTS
s = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice") #INITS VOICE
r = sr.Recognizer() #INITS RECOGNIZER
done = False
#FUNCTIONS
def Main(comm):
    while True:
        done = input("\nPress key to talk..")
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            comm = r.recognize_google(audio)
            comm = comm.lower()
            print(comm) #for debugging
            if comm in open("search_triggers.txt").read():
               print("working") #if key word found, program prints 'working'



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main('x')
```

Comment: Add the code into the question itself. No screenshots

Comment: sorry, all done:)